Double integral with parameter
I'm an italian student in Mathematics and I'm struggling with the following double integral that I found in a list of exercises given by a teacher (Calculus II) a few years ago:
$$I=\iint_A \dfrac{1}{\ln^2{x}+\ln^2{y}}\cdot \dfrac{1}{xy}\,dx\,dy$$
where $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x+y\geq 1, x^{\alpha}+y^{\alpha}\leq 1\}$, $\alpha\in [1,+\infty[$
Here is a picture of $A$ with $\alpha=2, \alpha=5, \alpha=9$ (from left to right):

I have to prove that $I=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{\alpha}$
My attempt 1:
$$I=\int_0^1\int_{1-x}^{(1-x^{\alpha})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}\dfrac{1}{\ln^2{x}+\ln^2{y}}\cdot \dfrac{1}{xy}\,dy\,dx=\int_0^1\biggl[\dfrac{1}{x\ln{x}}\arctan{\dfrac{\ln{y}}{\ln{x}}}\biggr]_{1-x}^{(1-x^{\alpha})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}\,dx$$
but now I can't find a way to calculate the last improper integral.
My attempt 2:
I tried with a change of variables, $u=\ln{x}, v=\ln{y}$:
$$I=\iint_B \dfrac{1}{u^2+v^2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{e^u\cdot e^v}\cdot e^{u+v}\,du\,dv=\iint_B \dfrac{1}{u^2+v^2}\,du\,dv$$
where $B=\{(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2: e^u+e^v\geq 1, e^{\alpha u}+e^{\alpha v}\leq 1\}$, $\alpha\in [1,+\infty[$
Now the function is much simpler but the domain can't be described in a simple way. So I am at the starting point again.
Any help would be appreciated.

Note that $x, y \leq 1$ as otherwise $x^{\alpha} + y^{\alpha} \geq 2$. Moreover, for $\alpha = 2$, this corresponds to the segment bound by the line $x+y=1$ and $x^2+y^2 = 1$. For any higher $\alpha$, I am unfamiliar with what kind of shape will be generated. If you use the bounds of integration as $0$ and $1$ from the inequality in this comment, I think you should be able to find your answer using the properties of the gaussian integral.

Thanks for your answer @Kraken. Increasing the value of $\alpha$, the shape of the domain becomes similar to a triangle (inside [0,1]x[0,1]).

Maybe you could turn it into a contour integral using Green's Theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem

Call the integral $I(\alpha)$ and take its derivative with respect to $\alpha$. Since the only dependence on $\alpha$ is through the upper limit of the $y$-integral, we get
\begin{align}
I'(\alpha) &= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln^2 x + \frac1{\alpha^2}\ln^2(1-x^\alpha)} \cdot \frac{1}{x (1-x^\alpha)^{\frac1\alpha}} \cdot \frac{d}{d\alpha}\left((1-x^\alpha)^{\frac1\alpha}\right)~dx
\\
&= -\int_0^1 \frac{x^\alpha\ln x^\alpha + (1 - x^\alpha) \ln(1 - x^\alpha)}{x(1 - x^\alpha) [\ln^2 x^\alpha + \ln^2(1 - x^\alpha)]}~dx
\\
&= -\frac1\alpha\int_0^1 \frac{z\ln z + (1 - z) \ln(1 - z)}{z (1 - z) [\ln^2 z + \ln^2(1 - z)]}~dz
\end{align}
where I substituted $z=x^\alpha$ to get the last line. It is easy to verify that the antiderivative of the integrand is $\arctan\left(\frac{\ln z}{\ln(1-z)}\right)$, so the integral is
$$
I'(\alpha) = -\frac1\alpha \left[ \arctan\left(\frac{\ln z}{\ln(1-z)}\right) \right]_0^1 = \frac{\pi}{2\alpha}.
$$
Since $I(1) = 0$, we conclude that
$$
I(\alpha) = \frac\pi2 \ln \alpha.
$$

I had the idea of taking the derivative of $I(\alpha)$ with respect to $\alpha$, but I stopped at the first line. Thanks a lot @Pranay
